# EXISTS in filter returning too many values

Tags: t-sql, ssms, exists

I need to write a query that uses EXISTS, rather than IN, so that it will run fast. The filter is being fed so many parameter values that EXISTS seems like the only option. The difference is between a 20+ minute query and a 5 second query.

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.GROUP_NAME
FROM [EMPLOYEE] e JOIN [DATA_FACT] d ON (e.KEY = d.KEY)
WHERE d.DATE BETWEEN @Start and @End
AND EXISTS
(              
    select '1234567' -- @ID
) 
AND e.Location IN (@Location)
ORDER BY d.GROUP_NAME ASC
```

The problem is that it is returning too many records. Based on the values I'm passing to filter on, I should get 1 row back but instead I am getting 28.

If I remove the EXISTS and add the following then I get the 1 record I need:

```
AND e.ID IN ('1234567')
```

Is there a way to fix the query to work with EXISTS so that I get the correct results?

Comment: Where does the `'1234567'` come from?

Comment: @JoshPart, the value comes from SSRS via a parameter. The parameter will have many values. But for simplicity I've removed the parameter in the above code, and hard coded that dummy value

Comment: Exists is usually used to correlate an outer query to an inner query. Your current version will return all of your records because you have no check condition.

Comment: I bet that 20+ minute query is not being slowed by an IN statement. You might want to take a look into other factors. I would add a WITH RECOMPILE and clear your statistics and run a few more tests first.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock, what do you mean by "because you have no check condition"? How do I fix this?

Comment: @RossBush, I've already tried OPTION (RECOMPILE) for the version of the query that uses the IN. Made no difference

Comment: @RossBush the problem is that he wants to put up to 8,000 parameters in the IN statement. Not sure why an EXISTS would outperform an IN, unless IN doesn't short circuit.

Zolt - go look at examples of EXISTS(), you need a where clause that references something in your outer query for EXISTS() to do it's job

Comment: @Zolt As mentioned earlier, the issue is most likely _not_ due to IN vs EXISTS, rather it is due to some other underlying performance issues in your DB. Why don't you try to take the query which is built out from SSRS using the IN clause, and running it in SSMS with the query plan showing? That should give you some inkling as to what the issues are.

Comment: I think you don't really get how `EXISTS` works: basically, for every row, it executes the query inside the `EXISTS` clause and, if the clause returns any value, the current row is returned, if it doesn't return values, the current row is ignored. What you current query does is, for every one of the 28 rows in your table that fulfill the other filters (date and having a matching record on `DATA_FACT`), it checks if `SELECT @ID` returns something; as you're directly selecting the parameter variable, it will always return something, that's why it selects the 28 rows. -->

Comment: --> If your problem is that using `IN` with all the values you receive slows down your query, you might want to try putting them first inside a temporary table or a table variable, as `EXISTS` doesn't work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what you want if you are going to try to use exists to filter your data_fact table by parameters in your employee table. Not sure how much it's going to improve your performance though when you throw a massive number of employee IDs at it.

```
SELECT 
    d.GROUP_NAME
FROM [DATA_FACT] AS d
WHERE d.DATE BETWEEN @Start and @End
AND EXISTS
(              
    select 1
    from EMPLOYEE AS e
    WHERE d.[KEY] = e.[KEY]
        AND e.[Location] IN (@Location)
        AND e.ID IN ('1234567')
)
ORDER BY d.GROUP_NAME ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggested answer but the problem is that the sub query still has the `AND e.ID IN ('1234567')`. So this in turn slows down the query again. My hope was to use EXISTS instead of IN to make it run faster

Comment: You can't substitute an EXISTS for an IN, they perform entirely different functions. IN checks a variable in each record against another list. EXISTS checks for the existence of a condition. Your original question from yesterday had very good answers. You need to spend some time educating yourself on SQL instead of constantly reposting the same question without taking the time to read the answers and learn the underlying problem